# Show git diff for file where contents is different but modified timestamp is the same

Tags: git, diff

We have a file where the contents has been modified, but the timestamp of the file was reset to the original timestamp before modification.

When doing a git diff  it does not report any differences, nor does git status show that the file has been modified.

I'd like to find files that are similar to this one on the file system where the file has been modified, but the timestamp is the same as pre-modification.  Is there a git command that will show all files that have been modified by using a means other than the file modified timestamp?

Comment: Can you try `git update-index --really-refresh` and see if it helps?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this behavior; AFAIK `git diff` shouldn't depend on the timestamps.  Are you sure the changes haven't been locally committed?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.  git blame shows there are lines "Not Committed Yet" and git diff --stat --cached origin/master returns nothing.

Comment: @rodrigo your command shows the updated file.  Awesome, thanks so much!

Comment: @user2966697 do not use `--cached`